# How to draw a line in diagonal direction on a widget android

Tags: android

I want to know is there a simple way to draw a line in diagonal direction, like using `<View .... /View>` in xml to draw line in vertical or horizontal direction.

Below is the image of what I want to do

Selected form of button
[image]

Unselected form of button
[image]

Changing color of text is not a problem, its drawing line for unselected case and making invisible for selected one. Thank you

Comment: Override `onDraw()` of `View` and add a line based on some flag.

Comment: Or you could also add an overlay view containing that diagonal line. While easier it that will give you bad stretch in wider views.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a transparent image with diagonal line and add that image as an overlay.

or create an shape xml of diagonal and add in your drawable. 
below is code to create diagonal shape.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
  <rotate
   android:fromDegrees="160"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:toDegrees="0">
   <shape
    android:shape="line"
    android:top="1dip">
    <stroke
       android:width="3dp"
       android:color="#FF0000"/>
         </shape>
         </rotate>
         </item>
         </layer-list>
```