# Create Diagonal Line in Drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

Want to achieve something like this:

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639) Also see [Draw diagonal line from corner to corner inside RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48281022/608639), [How to draw a line in diagonal direction on a widget android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43674186/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a drawable for a diagonal line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:toDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="yourcolor" />
        </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* answers. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Sorry Sir, my bad.  

By the way, had other approach but not using layer-list. Just rotated the button. 

`android:rotation="30"`

Answer (score 0):

Diagonal line can be drawn using following code in drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:toDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="line" >
            <stroke
                android:width="3dip"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: why you mark it is not useful..can you tell me problem in above code

Comment: Thank you Sir @Rishav! Will try this one now & give feedback.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13_k4eVL3mEqyHkRCDPv6cOgE89aT3iLr

Want to achieve something like this, having top point of diagonal equal to top right of view & bottom point of diagonal point equal to bottom right of view. :)

Comment: @ShemAlexisChavez for this you have to set your rotate property i.e fromDegrees & toDegrees according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by creating a custom view class that extends View or TextView(subclass of view).
Check sample image : [screenshot of diagonally cut view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B55dj.png)

Create a kotlin class that extends AppCompatTextView in Utility folder.
Classname -  CustomDiagonalView

```
`package <your_package>

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import <package>.R


class CustomDiagonalView : AppCompatTextView {
    private var dividerColor = 0
    private var paint: Paint? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, 
    attrs) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : 
    super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    ) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        val resources: Resources = context.resources
        //replace with your color
        dividerColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
R.color.colorGrey97)
        paint = Paint()
        paint?.color = dividerColor
        //replace with your desired width
        paint?.strokeWidth = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.margin_1)
    }

 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.drawLine(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), 0f, 0f, 
    paint!!)
}
}
```

If you want your diagonal line to be like : [screenshot of view striking from top-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx3nK.png) , then simply replace the params of canvas drawline -

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawLine(0f, height.toFloat(), width.toFloat(), 0f, 
        paint!!)
    }
```

Now, in your xml class, call it like :

```
<com.package.CustomDiagonalView
            android:id="@+id/txtDiagonalStrike"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            tools:text="Custom Text"/>
```

Hope it will help.
Happy coding!! :)